# submit form and check for complete without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I need to submit a form and check for its completion without using the submit button.

I managed to submit it trough `document.getElementById('logoForm').submit();`, but now I need to call a function if the form was successfully submitted.

My form:

```
<form name="logoForm" id="logoForm" method="POST" target="frame" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="includes/uplLogo.php">
```

Submit function:

```
$("#file1").change(function() {
        document.getElementById('logoForm').submit();
        //setTimeout(reloadImg, 2000) this was how i called the next function but its not safe at all
        alert('submited');
    });
```

The function I want to be called on a successful submit:

```
 function reloadImg(){
    var exists = document.getElementById('AppId').value; 
            $.post("includes/step_img.php", {id: exists}, function(data){
                document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML=data;
            });

}
```

Comment: Amazing mix of pure JavaScript and jQuery...

Comment: Submitting the form causes the page to refresh with the new contents. There *is* nothing that runs after a submit.  You could seralize the form and submit via AJAX though

Comment: http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/

Comment: assuming `$("#file1")` is a file input will also need to read up on uploading files by ajax if that is route you take

Comment: there is no simpler way to do this? i mean @charlietfl is right i need to submit the form when file1 (input:file) is clicked. then i need to check for complection not for success...

Comment: no there isn't a simpler way unless you handle the post processing server side

Comment: success callback ins´t working... i tried the example from here hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit  and nothing happends

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the form using AJAX, otherwise you will have a page reload, rendering all your JS void.

This is how you could do it with jQuery

```
//bind to submit
$("#logoForm").submit(function(e)
{
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            reloadImg();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            //if fails
            alert("ERROR");      
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});

$("#logoForm").submit(); //Submit  the FORM
```

Comment: yea but now the code inside step_img.php ins´t good... i have to post the input file data... like this $file_name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it working!!

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    $("#file1").change(function() {
        //bind to submit
        $("#logoForm").submit(function(e)
        {
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data: new FormData( this ),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    reloadImg();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    //if fails
                    alert("ERROR");      
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
            e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
        });
        $("#logoForm").submit(); //Submit  the FORM
    });

});

function reloadImg(){
    var exists = document.getElementById('AppId').value; 
    $.post("includes/step_img.php", {id: exists}, function(data){
        document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML=data;
    });
}
```

but once i click the file input i have to reload the page to make it work again... any ideas how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

As Regent said: "Amazing mix of pure JavaScript and jQuery"

if you will be using jquery first of all you will need to include the jquery library, I don't know if you did that.
Also, if you are working with jquery try to use all that jquery provide you to write less code.

Seeing your code I am assuming that you have a form with a input type file into. And when a file is loaded to the field, you want to submit the form. Also the form is targetted to a frame, so I am assuming that you have an iframe element there too.

To know if the form was successfully submitted you can use an ajax request but in this case your are sending files with the form, so you can not use an ajax request.
You can return a javascript code in your response that will be executed from into the iframe so, you can access to the parent element to do that you want

I have modified a little bit your code to integrate jQuery at all.

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/latest/jquery.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery("#file1").change(function() {
                    jQuery('#logoForm').submit();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="logoForm" id="logoForm" method="POST" target="frame" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="includes/uplLogo.php">
            <input type="file" name="file1"  id="file1" />
        </form>
        <iframe name="frame"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in your includes/uplLogo.php you need to return the javascript code to execute a similar of reloadImg()

So, in your includes/uplLogo.php you could have:

```
<?php
...
Your code here
...

if($all_is_ok) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/latest/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var id = jQuery('#AppId', window.parent.document).val();
            jQuery.post("includes/step_img.php", {id: id}, function(data) {
                jQuery('#imgDiv', window.parent.document).html(data);
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

I have not tested it because I just wrote it but I think that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment this line: e.unbind();

Try also to add a log just after the input file changes, and verify if you can see the log in the js console:

```
...
$("#file1").change(function() {
    console.log('input file changed');
    //bind to submit
...
```

Answer (score 0):

for those who will need this in the future the problem was:

```
    $("#file1").change(function()
```

i just changed that to:

```
function changed()
```

and add it to input on onchange method!